# Is there a standard C++ function to print a generated array as a string usable in initialization of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, syntax, format

I'm currently working on a Dual Contouring implementation, and I'm seeking to optimize it using lookup tables to quickly iterate through intersected edges.

Trouble is, I'm not entirely sure what the standard go-to method is to generate lookup tables.

Is there a standard function that can be used to print out an array to console as a value, formatted as a ready-to-use value to paste into variable declaration?

Such as this:

```cpp
//The following array
int newArray[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}};
//would print out a string like the following:
"{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 2}}"
```

I am absolutely open to writing such a function myself, but I would really like to clarify if it already exists, just so I'm not reinventing a bicycle.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No there is no such function in the C++ library. But this sounds like an XY problem. What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one about finding a function that formats things this way, but the problem to which you believe this is the solution, and that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Oh, I'm just trying to optimize my Dual Contouring implementation. I'm looking to generate a lookup table similar to the lookup table used by Marching Cubes, except  in my case the lookup table isn't generating triangles, but simply allows me to skip individual checking of every edge of a cell and jump straight to the edges that I would *know* contain and intersection via the lookup tables.

Comment: So the problem is about producing the lookup tables, really. I'm simply looking for a way to be able to get the array generated, and then get it hardcoded into my program as const int array.

Comment: There is a [serialization library as part of `boost`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#arrays) , but that may now do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Can your generator function be `constexpr`? then you won't need to output that array.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!